# Inner join using Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I have a User:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = UserEntity.TABLE_NAME)
public class UserEntity {
  ...
  private List<TeamEntity> teams = new ArrayList<TeamEntity>();
  ...
  @ManyToMany(mappedBy="users" , fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  public List<TeamEntity> getTeams() {
    return teams;
  }
}
```

and a Team:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = TeamEntity.TABLE_NAME)
public class TeamEntity {
   ...
   private List<UserEntity> users = new ArrayList<UserEntity>();
   ...
   @ManyToMany (fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinTable(name= TeamEntity.TEAM_USER_TABLE,joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name=TeamEntity.TEAM_ID, referencedColumnName="ID",
      insertable = true, updatable = false, nullable = false),
      inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name=TeamEntity.USER_ID, referencedColumnName="ID",
      insertable = true, updatable = false, nullable = false),
      uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {TeamEntity.TEAM_ID, TeamEntity.USER_ID}))
  public List<UserEntity> getUsers() {
    return users;
  }
}
```

If I have an id of the user, what is the HQL query to retrieve all the teams that a user is a member of?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are not doing a where on the inner join, I wouldn't bother using HQL...

Because you are using Lazy loading, you have to initialize the teams collection... if you were using Eager fetching, you would not need the second line.

```
UserEntity user = (UserEntity) session.byId(UserEntity.class).load(id);
Hibernate.initialize(user.getTeams());
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to query those is following JQPL (HQL being more or less superset of JPQL):

```
SELECT t 
FROM UserEntity u 
JOIN u.teams t 
WHERE u.id = :userId
```